# How Interfaces Will Help in Real time Scenario?

Tags: c#, mvc

I'm working in a real-time project. They are using 3 tier architecture using interfaces but I am not getting how it will work as Dependency injection.
I know interfaces can be multiply-inherited and have some theoretical knowledge. I need a brief discussion about how interfaces can be used in a real-time context.

Comment: What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: DI happens before "real time". It's about object construction typically done in main while the user is looking at a splash screen. After that your code will work as fast as it ever did.

Comment: "Interfaces" and "real-time" are orthogonal concepts, they have actually not much in common. This makes your question sound like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Please clarify why you think there is a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purposes, think of dependency injection as *handing a class the objects it depends on through its constructor.*

To avoid tight coupling with the dependencies you pass in, the parameters to your constructor should be *interfaces.*  That way, you can pass in whatever implementation you want, so long as it conforms to the interface you specified.

Example (in Java):

```
public interface Soundable {
  void makeNoise();
} 

public class OogaHorn implements Soundable {
  public void makeNoise() {
    System.out.println("OOGA!");
  }
}

public class WimpyHorn implements Soundable {
  public void makeNoise() {
    System.out.println("Beep!");
  }
}

public class Car {
  Soundable horn;

  public Car(Soundable s) {
    horn = s;
  }

  public void SoundHorn() {
    horn.makeNoise();
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Soundable horn = new OogaHorn(); // Specify which horn you want here.
    Car car = new Car(horn);

    car.SoundHorn(); // OOGA!
  }
}
```